# Upper half the characters entered in EditText field are not visible

Tags: android

In Android Project, upper half of the characters entered in the EditText field are not visible. I tried reducing the fonts from 25sp to 18sp, more part of the letters visible but problem still persists. Reducing font size less than that looks odd in the app. I tried on Margins and padding too, but no result. Please help.

[image: Scree Shot of the problem]

**Part of the Layout file :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4ab4b2"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="427dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lableDenom"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="Denom"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lableQty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Qty"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lableValue"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="Value"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lable2000"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/Rs_2000"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="2000"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/qty2000"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result2000"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/Rs_2000"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />


        </TableRow>  ... ...
```

Comment: have you tried setting the height to wrap content instead of fix dp? you can also reduce char size

Comment: Intially it was wrap content, but wrap content pushing the table rows down. As there are lot of rows, i could not accomodate all. So i gave a fixed size to the edittext field. But my doubt is why that bottom line is not aligning with the other textview fields on both sides of it. 

I tried to give negative padding -10dp to bring the bottom line down, but no use.

Comment: Further the sizes of Textviews on its both sides have same height of 35dp and character size of 25dp. Still those characters are fully visible.

Comment: it is because the middle one is not a textview, it is an edittext and it is a quite different component. You can try styling the edittext to look like a textview

Comment: You need to increase the height of the edittext. Try 40dp or greater in edittext height. I tried it in your code and it is not cutting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an simple solution for the above problem by googling with different question **How to remove the underbar in `EditText` field.**

By adding the following code to `EditText`, the problem is solved. Now I can keep `layout_height` at `35dp` and `textSize` at `25sp`.

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4ab4b2"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="427dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lableDenom"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="Denom"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lableQty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Qty"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lableValue"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="Value"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lable2000"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:background="@color/Rs_2000"
                android:text="2000"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/qty2000"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result2000"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/Rs_2000"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

increase your `edittext` height according to your code UI as you want and `textsize` 25sp to 22sp, `textPadding` 5dp to 4dp.

Comment: All text sizes in TextView are 25sp. Actually i wanted same size for EditText also. As suggested by you, I tried 40dp for height and 25sp to 22sp for text. But same problem persists. I tried wrap_content option. it is working but pushing the rows down and as there are so many rows, screen size could not accommodate. isn't there a solution to push the bottom line in EditText field further down to align with the TextView.

Comment: thengive  same height to everyone and make text size 20sp

Comment: is it compulsory to give text size 25sp?

Comment: Not compulsory. But I wanted keep text sizes for all the fields same and that looks nice. For `TextView` I kept `35dp` for height and `25sp` for `textsize`. I felt that combination proportionately looking good. I expected same for `EditText` field, but not working. I thought if i could push the bottom line in `EditText` to align with the other `TextView`s, It may work. I am seaching in the google for the right attribute to do. so